# How to share picture on Google+?

Tags: objective-c, ios, google-plus

Our two teams are developing same app: adroid team and iOS team. Android team was able to do text + photo sharing. Simple post with text is done normally but text + image requires google+ app and the code that opens small center'ed web view looks like this:

```
Intent shareIntent = ShareCompat.IntentBuilder.from(act)
 .setText(message).setStream(uri).setType("image/jpeg")
 .getIntent().setPackage("com.google.android.apps.plus");
act.startActivityForResult(shareIntent, SocialNetworksConstants.GOOGLE_POST_REQUERST);
```

However, I can't find anything similar in the newest Google+ iOS sdk. GPPShareBuilder protocol only has:

```
- (id<GPPShareBuilder>)setPrefillText:(NSString *)prefillText;
```

and

```
- (id<GPPShareBuilder>)setTitle:(NSString *)title
                       description:(NSString *)description
                       thumbnailURL:(NSURL *)thumbnailURL;
```

Has anybody faced this problem?

**UPDATE**: Here's a [link](http://googleplusplatform.blogspot.com/2012/05/sharing-rich-content-from-your-android.html) to solution for Android. It looks like Android has some "ShareCompat" Android native library that extends functionality for sharing data between apps.

**UPDATE2** Tried to use "setTitle:description:thumbnailURL:" with google+ sharing sample code in recent Google+ sdk. Tried to push NSURL of some image from bundle:

```
- (IBAction)shareButton:(id)sender{
  ...
  if (title && description) {

  //NSURL *imageUrl = [NSURL URLWithString:[deepLinkThumbnailURL_ text]];

  NSString *imagePathString = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"my_image" ofType:@"png"];
  NSURL *imageUrl = [[NSURL alloc] initWithString:imagePathString];

  shareBuilder = [shareBuilder setTitle:title
                            description:description
                           thumbnailURL:imageUrl]; // throw image path
}
```

However that didn't work out. Image placeholder is empty when google+ opens sharing window in safari. Only some external URL link is working.

Answer (score 0):

**Use this :**

```
NSData *imageData = UIImagePNGRepresentation(myImage.image);

[(id< GPPNativeShareBuilder >)shareBuilder attachImageData:imageData];
```